# How to sort a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to pass a character vector to a dataframe to sort it. How Can I do this? I have tried the following

```
headings.tosort <- c("mpg", "hp")
headings <- intersect(headings.tosort, names(mtcars))

mtcars[with(mtcars,order(headings)),]
mtcars[with(mtcars,order(mpg,hp)),]
```

I want to be able to create a vector with a list of  headings to sort and then call it in a  dataframe. The first expression does not work but the second one does so how do I get this to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I maybe misunderstood your question, but I would do like that:

```
mtcars[do.call(order, mtcars[, headings]), ]
```